# Draggable item inside a (fixed-height) div messes up the CursorAt position

Tags: jquery, html, height, draggable, scrollable

I have the following setup:

```
<asp:treeview cssclass="draggable"><items...>  <table />
```

And I set it up to be able to drag items from the treeview to the table, using jQuery:

```
 $(".draggable").draggable({ helper: "clone", cursorAt: { left: -10, top: -10} })
```

So while dragging, the clone is meant to stay a little underneath the current mouse position, to make it easier for the user.

However, I now need to make the treeview scrollable (vertically) when the open nodes would push it beyond a simple page of content, otherwise drag-and-drop becomes too hard for the users.

To this extent, I've put a scrollable div around the treeview, as follows:

```
<div style="padding-right: 20px; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height: 300px;"> <asp:treeview cssclass="draggable"><items...></div>  <table />
```

This works as expected, but the problem is now that - while dragging - the cloned element is no longer just below the mouse position, but instead way down, which is of course very confusing for the user.

I've tried removing the "cursorAt" property of the draggable() method, but this doesn't help.

So it seems the fixed height of the div is messing up the position of the cloned element... any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer was that CursorAt will default to the parent of the dragged item, which in this case had changed to a div.

So changing the draggable() to

```
 $("draggable").draggable({ helper: "clone", appendTo:'body', cursorAt: { left: -10, top: -10} })
```

fixed the problem.